# Is using firebase without using firebase rules a bad approach?

Tags: next.js, firebase-security

I'm working on a project made with NextJS and I'm using firebase services. When I started working on the authentication and security of the project I began using firebase security rules and I found out that they are really limited for the things I want to do. Also, the testing interface firebase provides is really poor which leads to wasting a lot of time in testing each rule.

That's why I thought of not using firebase security rules. Instead of that, I'd send every request from the client to the nextjs server, then the server sends the request using firebase admin SDK. The security rules operations are set to false so that the only way to make a request is through the server, and the server is the one that validates every request.

This approach works but I'm wondering if it's the best one, given that firebase was designed to be used with their security rules. I want to know if firebase security rules are in fact limited or I'm just not using them correctly. And, in case they are limited, I want to know if I'm taking a good path or maybe it's just better to not use firebase at all.

Comment: Basic answer below. There's no way for us to answer "I want to know if firebase security rules are in fact limited or I'm just not using them correctly" without seeing a [minimal reproduction of where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't provide much detail, I know it always depends on the project and it's really situational but as I noticed that firebase security rules didn't work for me I wanted to know if that happened to other people as well. It's more of a general question just to know that I'm not taking a wrong path.

Comment: "firebase security rules didn't work for me" is not something we can objectively judge. Many developer struggle writing rules, but I typically don't. Knowing either of those doesn't help anyone (as you're not me, and nobody else is either of us), hence the ask for always posting a concrete problem on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The security rules operations are set to false

So you actually **are** using security rules, but not allowing any direct access from the client-side SDKs. That is a completely valid approach.

Comment: Right. What I meant by not using security rules is that I'm not using the ones that firebase provides and instead I'm validating everything in the next.js server. That's why my main concern was if maybe I was adding an unnecessary "layer" to the application (client to server -> server to firebase) and maybe it was not the best practice.
Thanks for answering.